# Date and Time defaulting to Jan 01, 1AD in Lubridate R package

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, lubridate

folks...

I am having trouble with date/time showing up properly in lubridate.

Here's my code:

```
Temp.dat <- read_excel("Temperature Data.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", na="NA") %>%
  mutate(Treatment = as.factor(Treatment),
         TempC=as.factor(TempC),
         TempF=as.factor(TempF),
         Month=as.factor(Month),
         Day=as.factor(Day),
         Year=as.factor(Year),
         Time=as.factor(Time))%>%
 select(TempC, Treatment, Month, Day, Year, Time)%>%
 mutate(Measurement=make_datetime(Month, Day, Year, Time))
```

Here's what it spits out:

```
tibble [44 x 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ TempC      : Factor w/ 38 levels "15.5555555555556",..: 31 32 29 20 17 28 27 26 23 24 ...
 $ Treatment  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Grass","Soil": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Month      : Factor w/ 1 level "6": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Day        : Factor w/ 2 levels "15","16": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year       : Factor w/ 1 level "2022": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Time       : Factor w/ 3 levels "700","1200","1600": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 **$ Measurement: POSIXct[1:44], format: "0001-01-01 03:00:00" "0001-01-01 03:00:00" "0001-01-01 03:00:00" "0001-01-01 03:00:00" ...**
```

I've put asterisks by the problem result. It should spit out June 16th at 0700 or something like that, but instead it's defaulting to January 01, 1AD for some reason. I've tried adding colons to the date in excel, but that defaults to a 12-hour timecycle and I'd like to keep this at 24 hours.

What's going on here?

Comment: Factoring seconds and temperature does not seem logical to me. Factoring a continuous variable will basically make a level for each entry, which as you see in TempC, you have 38 levels. Try not factoring temps and time. Import time as date, specifying the format you have in the excel file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Would you mind expanding on this a little bit?

I'm not sure how my temperature data would affect my date/time data. I'm also not using seconds in my measurements, just hours.

Comment: Sure, temp does not affect the problem of time. It was just an observation. `make_datetime()` is expecting `make_datetime(year = 1999, month = 12, day = 22, sec = 10)`. Grab the time portion of the `Time` that contains the time and split it into hours, minutes, and seconds. I don't know how your time data is coming in to help you split it, if you post a row of the data before you transform it (as it comes when you read it with `read_excel()`) I can write a proper answer.

Comment: I know you're not using seconds...

Comment: Here's how it's coming in, using the code before the pipes. I'm not sure how to post a comment so it codes properly unfortunately.

`tibble [44 x 10] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Stake    : chr [1:44] "4r" "10r" "16r" "22r" ...
 $ Treatment: Factor w/ 2 levels "Grass","Soil": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Month    : int [1:44] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Day      : int [1:44] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...`

Comment: The info for `Time` got cut off, can you edit your post and include the contents of your data? You can store the output of the file `tmp <- read_excel( .. )` and then post the first few rows `head(tmp)`. You can also post `str(tmp$Time)` to see the type.

Comment: Here is str(tmp$Time)

`int [1:44] 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 1600 ...`

Comment: Here are the first few rows of Head(tmp)

`Year
<int>
Month
<int>
Day
<int>
Time
<int>
TempC
<fctr>
Treatment
<fctr>
Measurement
<S3: POSIXct>
2022 6 15 1600 31.5 Grass 2022-08-20 16:00:00
2022 6 15 1600 31.7 Grass 2022-08-20 16:00:00`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245706/discussion-between-guasi-and-joe-ballenger).

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as the format in the excel file for date is set to time, and it imports as a date-time object that `lubridate` can interpret.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Temp.dat <- read_excel("t.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", na="NA") %>%
  mutate(Treatment = as.factor(Treatment),
         TempC = as.numeric(TempC),
         TempF = as.numeric(TempF),
         Month = as.numeric(Month),
         Day = as.numeric(Day),
         Year = as.numeric(Year),
         Hour = hour(Time),
         Minute = minute(Time)) %>%
  select(TempC, Treatment, Month, Day, Year, Hour, Minute) %>%
  mutate(Measurement = make_datetime(year = Year, 
                                     month = Month, 
                                     day = Day, 
                                     hour = Hour,
                                     min = Minute))
```

Notice the value for the arguments for `make_datetime()` are set to numeric, which is what the function expects. If you pass factors, the function gives you the weird dates you were seeing.

No need to convert `Time` to string and extract hours and minutes, as I suggested in the comments, since you can use lubridate's `minute()` and `hour()` functions.

**EDIT**
In order to be able to use lubridate's functions `Time` needs to be a date-time object. You can check that it is by looking at what `read_excel()` produces

```
> str(read_excel("t.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1", na="NA"))
tibble [2 × 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)                                                     
 $ Treatment: chr [1:2] "s" "c"
 $ TempC    : num [1:2] 34 23
 $ TempF    : num [1:2] 99 60
 $ Month    : num [1:2] 5 4
 $ Day      : num [1:2] 1 15
 $ Year     : num [1:2] 2020 2021
 $ Time     : POSIXct[1:2], format: "1899-12-31 04:33:23" "1899-12-31 03:20:23"
```

See that `Time` is type `POSIXct`, a date-time object. If it is not, then you need to convert it into one if you want to use lubridate's `minute()` and `hour()` functions. If it cannot be converted, there are other solutions, but they depend on what you have.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

I'm getting the following error code:

`Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `Hour`.
i `Hour = hour(Time)`.
x 'origin' must be supplied`

What is this origin referring to?

Comment: It's possible `Time` is not formatted as a date-time object, but it's hard to tell without seeing the structure and contents of the data produced by `read_excel()` **before** it gets passed on to `mutate()`. You've tried to post it in the comments, but it gets cut off and it's really hard to read. You can **edit** your post instead. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) explains how to grab and post data.

Comment: I went back the comments, and I see that `Time` is coming in as an `int [1:44] 1600`. What's this 1600? minutes?

Comment: I eventually got this to work. The issue was that I had a column in my data for time, when I should have split it into hours and minutes.

`$ TempC      : num [1:88] 31.5 31.7 31.2 27.2 26.4 30.7 30.3 29.3 28.4 28.6 ...
 $ Treatment  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Grass","Soil": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Month      : int [1:88] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ Day        : int [1:88] 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 ...
 $ Year       : int [1:88] 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 2022 ...
 $ Hour       : int [1:88] 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16`